# Where to find full details of PIC12F1822 assembly code instructions

Tags: assembly, documentation, pic

I have been programming PICs in assembly language for a long time, and have begun a project which will use a PIC12F1822 as an I2C master. I have seen (and lost) a note that the `call` and `return` instructions automatically store and retrieve the status and working registers values, and others, something I am used to doing with several lines of code for the PIC12F675. And there are quite a few additional instructions that are available. There is a summary in the datasheet, but I cannot find the  detailed descriptions I need among the bewildering plethora of documentation out there.

Please can someone point me to where this information is to be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the document you need ?

If so, you can find the entire PDF file here...

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41413C.pdf

Run down to chapter 29, "INSTRUCTION SET SUMMARY", page 327 (I think) with the actual stuff starting five pages later. The first four pages are nomenclature and syntax junk.

If not, my second best suggestion is to hunt through this list of sixteen manuals...

http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en544839

No promise that either of these will lead you out of the woods, but I tried.

Here's a screen cap from page 331 of the 41413C manual.

[image: Screen Cap Of Half A Page]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it has led me directly to the informationg I want, in  DS41375A, listed in the en544839 document.

Comment: I ran out of time on the previous comment which can be ignored or deleted. Thank you @user 1 for your answer, it has led me directly to the information I want, in  DS41375A, listed in the en544839 document. I already had a copy of the data sheet for the pic12f1822, which contains the page samples you reproduce, and your refernce has given me an up to date version, but the RETFIE there, page 38 still does not mention the context resoration. At a first glance it all looks very much like the PIC18f... that I have already used, very nice. Thank you again.